# SQL Query to Find Maximum Length of EmpName column column

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

How to Find MAXIMUM Length of EmpName Column from Employee Table.
EmpName:
Umesh
Umesh Patel
Vishwajeet Kumar

What Sql Query i Should Write to find MAXIMUM Length of EmpName Column.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(EmpName))
FROM Employee;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee4c5/2)

Answer (score 1):

If you want both the length and also the name of that employee:

```
select empname, len(empname) as len_of_name
  from employee
 where len(empname) = (select max(len(empname)) from employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maximum length an employee name and a sample:

```
select top 1 EmpName, len(EmpName)
from Employee
order by len(EmpName) desc;
```